# Compare previous date and current date and update the table on basis on condition

Tags: sql-server

I want to update my attendance table on basis of the following condition.

`NonWorking` type is 1 
If its previous day or next attendance type is Absent then I want to mark `NonWorking` type is LWP in DAOthers Column.

[image]

Comment: ...and what output do you expect?  Try to include text rather than images.

Comment: I am expecting if 2017-02-03  is Absent then i want to mark 2017-02-04 as LWP in DAOthers column

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `LAG()` and `LEAD()` here to peek at the preceding and proceeding values of the attendance type.  Then, if one of those should be absent, mark the `NonWorking` column appropriately.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
          LAG(AttendanceType,  1, 'Present') OVER (ORDER BY ADate) AS lag_at,
          LEAD(AttendanceType, 1, 'Present') OVER (ORDER BY ADate) AS lead_at
    FROM yourTable
)

UPDATE cte
SET NonWorking = 1
WHERE lag_at = 'Absent' OR lead_at = 'Absent'
```

Comment: Its not working actually its giving error of  Error converting data type varchar to bigint. i think its because of this LAG(AttendanceType,  'Present') OVER (ORDER BY ADate) AS lag_at line

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Sql Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you want an sql query to update existing data or a solution which is needed while making an entry.

## Use below query to update existing data:

```
Update AttendanceTable set DaOthers = 
 (select top 1 'LWP' from AttendanceTable at1 
  where AttendanceTable.EmployeeId = at1.EmployeeId 
  and DATEADD(day, -1,AttendanceTable.ADate) = at1.ADate 
  and at1.NonWorking = 1)
```

## Table befor executing above query:

[image]

## Table after executing above query:

[image]

## To update at the time of inserting record:

If you want to update while inserting data then you may need to set a variable first then use that variable while inserting. In the first query you need to use ADate and EmployeeID.The Nonworking is always 1.

```
DECLARE @DaOthers nvarchar(20) =  (select top 1 'LWP' from AttendanceTable    at
where DATEADD(day, 1, at.ADate) ='2017-02-04' and at.NonWorking = 1 and     EmployeeId = 1)

insert into AttendanceTable
(NonWorking, ADate, AttendanceType, EmployeeId, DaOthers)
values
(0,'2017-02-04', 'Present', 1,@DaOthers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With CTE as
(
SELECT *, 
DATEADD(DAY, 1, Lag(ADate, 1,ADate) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY   DAttendanceId ORDER BY   ADate ASC))   AS EndDate
FROM   tbl_DailyAttendance where EmployeeId = 1001 and AMonth = 2 and AYear = 2017 and AttendanceType = 'Absent' and NonWorking = 0
)
--select * from CTE
select  * from tbl_DailyAttendance tda inner join CTE c on tda.ADate = c.EndDate where tda.EmployeeID = 1001 and  tda.NonWorking = 1 order by tda.ADate
```

This is how i do for checking the conditions

Answer (score 0):

since you hvn't provided sample data,so try to understand my query and correct if anything minor.

```
;WITH CTE as
(
select  *
,isnull((select 1  from tbl_DailyAttendance tdb 
where ((tdb.adate=DATEADD(day,-1,tda.adate)) 
or (tdb.adate=DATEADD(day,1,tda.adate)))
and attendancetype='Absent'
),0) NewnonWorkingType

from tbl_DailyAttendance tda
)

--Testing purpose
--select * from cte

update tda
set nonworking=b.NewnonWorkingType
,daOther=case when b.NewnonWorkingType=1 then 'LWP' 
else null end
from tbl_DailyAttendance tda 
inner join cte b on tda.id=b.id
```